# CapRover app fails to find docker files path when deploying through Windows

Tags: windows, docker, path, caprover

I am not very familiar with CapRover, but my company uses it to deploy local branches to staging server. I completed a task in a ruby and rails project and tried to deploy my branch using the caprover deploy command.

The build passes, but the deployed app webpage goes to error 502. In the App Logs, it prints repeatedly that it could not find docker-entrypoint.sh: `/bin/sh: 1: docker-entrypoint.sh: not found`

Now, I use Windows and my colleagues use Linux. They tried to replicate the deploy on their machines and it is passing normally. That's why the suspicions falls on Windows causing it with some characters incompatibility, like slashes or quotations marks... I don't know how can I try to correct this issue without modifying the project files that they are already using and risk causing some problems where it is working...

I am not sure if I provided enough information for someone to try to help me fix this issue? I will gladly try to provide more infos if required
Thanks

Comment: One common form of trouble like this is DOS-style line endings, which could cause a Linux container to try to run `/bin/sh\r` as an interpreter and fail.  That's purely speculation, though, without being able to see a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidMaze ah I see, you mean LF or CRLF formatting right? I think you can be right. I will check it out. Thanks for the input!